# Best alternative solution for ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, controls, updatepanel

Best alternative solution for ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel for dynamically add and remove user controls without full postback

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use jQuery with ASP.NET Ajax PageMethods:

http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: First hyperlink doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Also, depending on exactly what you're trying to do, you may want to look at WebMethods for updating bits and pieces. I don't know about jQuery's support for it, I haven't used that. But you can use PageMethods, if you're doing simple stuff easily enough, without the need for jQuery.

http://www.codeasp.net/blogs/Vijjendra/microsoft-net/192/call-pagemethod-from-javascript-in-asp.net-ajax

Answer (score 0):

jQuery offers a bunch of handy AJAX calls. I'm not sure how well it would work with user controls but I'm sure you could manage something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ASP.Net Client Callbacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx) (here's [one walkthrough](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/programming-and-development/?p=642), there are lots out there) by implementing ICallbackEventHandler on your UserControls.  This avoids the full page postback, as it runs a modified version of the page lifecycle, but it has the advantage of keeping the UserControls in your page.

However I would also recommend jQuery if you can accomplish what you need with it.